# Creating a Java Car class

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm making a class with another separate driver class. The car class is for a Car Hire Company to store the information about the car like the make, model and registration number, so that using the driver class I can use to input new vehicles, check if a vehicle is on hire and unavailable and name of hirer if it is hired.

My car class with methods:

```
public class Car {

private String Make;
private String Model;
private int RegistrationNum;

public Car(String Make, String Model, String RegN){
    //Constructor,
    //stores the make, model and registration number of the new car
    //sets its status as available for hire.
    Make = "";
    Model = "";
    RegN = "";

}

public String getMake(){
    return Make;

}

public String getModel(){
    return Model;

}

public boolean hire(String newHirer){

    {
  //Hire this car to the named hirer and return true. 

        return true;
    }
  //Returns false if the car is already out on hire.



}

public boolean returnFromHire(){

    {
 //Receive this car back from a hire and returns true.
        return true;
    }

 //Returns false if the car was not out on hire     


}

public int getRego(){


 //Accessor method to return the car’s registration number      

    RegistrationNum++;
    return RegistrationNum;
    }



public boolean hireable(){
 //Accessor method to return the car’s hire status.     



    {
 //returns true if car available for hire           
    return true;    
    }
}

public String toString(){
 //return car details as formatted string
 //output should be single line containing the make model and reg number
 //followed by either "Available for hire" or "On hire to: <name>"


    return "Vehicle ID number: "+ getRego()+"-"+"Make is: "+ getMake()+"-"+"Model is: "+getModel();


}


}
```

Following is my Driver class:

```
  import java.util.*;
  public class CarDriver {
  static Car car1;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


{
    System.out.println("Make?");
    String Make=scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Model");
    String Model=scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Registration number?");
    String RegNum=scan.nextLine();

    car1 = new Car(Make,Model,RegNum);


    System.out.println("What you input :");

    System.out.println(car1.toString());
}}

 }
```

my output:

```
Make?
carmake
Model
carmodel
Registration number?
12345t
What you input :
Vehicle ID number: 1-Make is: null-Model is: null
```

Problems:

1. unable to understand how to convert the pseudocode for the
   boolean methods into java codes
2. unable to connect the driver
   class to store the information that I input, like the model, make
   and registration number

Comment: use this.Make,this.Model and this.red keyword in the constructor to store in instance variables

Comment: done =] anyways its actually not homework but revision questions

Comment: Your code would look a lot nicer if you didn't capitalise variable names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2nd

Change constructor to this one:

```
public Car(String Make, String Model, String RegN){
    this.Make = Make;
    this.Model= Model;
    this.RegN = RegN;
}
```

Your previous contructor had a problem, basically all you did was that you get the constructor arguments and set all of them to "" (empty string), you dont want to do that. You want to assign argument values to your instance fields. If you want to access instance fields you have to use keyword **this**.

```
public Car(String Make, String Model, String RegN){
//Constructor,
//stores the make, model and registration number of the new car
//sets its status as available for hire.
Make = "";
Model = "";
RegN = "";
```

}

Answer (score 1):

1st: In order to retrieve information about "whom is this car hired to" or "which driver has this car hired", you must **store** that information first.
What data type would you use? (remember this are "homeworks", I think it's better not to give *my* answer).

P.S: it's better to use non capitalized identifiers for variables and non-static/final attributes.

Answer (score 0):

As I see in the code, you don't set any fields of Car instance in the constructor. You should write smth like this:

```
public Car(String Make, String Model, String RegN){
    //Constructor,
    //stores the make, model and registration number of the new car
    //sets its status as available for hire.
    this.Make = Make;
    this.Model = Model;
    this.RegN = RegN;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your second question:

The moment you call:

```
car1 = new Car(Make,Model,RegNum);
```

The constructor of the Car class is called upon along with the variables you supplied.
When you take a look at the constructor you created:

```
public Car(String Make, String Model, String RegN){        
   Make = "";    
   Model = "";    
   RegN = "";   
}
```

You can see that the variables you provided are never set to the local variables of the Car class.
In order to fix this you need to change it intto the following:

```
public Car(String Make, String Model, String RegN){        
   this.Make  = Make;    
   this.Model = Model;    
   this.RegN   = RegN;   
}
```

Good luck on your program!

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling the constructor of `Car` class with your desired parameters, by default those parameter reference are sent to the constructor.

```
public Car(String Make, String Model, String RegN){        
   Make = "";    
   Model = "";    
   RegN = "";   
}
```

in the `Car` class constructor your parameters and member variables of your `Car` class have the same name. So when the constructor is called, the local variables are changed to empty string. And as the local variable contains the reference from the caller, so the original variables in the caller is also being changed. 
Again as you are not creating any instance to your class member reference, it still remains null.
If you use the following code segment in your constructor,

```
this.Make = "";    
this.Model = "";    
this.RegN = "";
```

`Car` class member variables will be changed instead of the variables from the caller.